# add recent *places* to finder sidebar

Tags: macos, finder

When I "open" or "save as" any file, there is a very convenient recent places drop down listing the latest five or so folders where I have saved things in.

I am very surprised that the same menu isn't directly accessible from finder. I've tried the smart folder with the "type=folder" + "last opened=1 day" but (1) it fails to return folders where I've only saved file to and (2) it can contain a very long list by the end of the day.

Does anyone know of a way to access those recent places directly from finder? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a "Recent Folders" menu under the Finder's "Go" menu:
[image: recent]